# Хочу покрасить ячейку через 7 или 6 строк

Tags: excel, vba

При открытии книги выходит InputBox в котором пользователь пишет точное количество или 6 или 7 строк после которых необходимо закрасить всю линию

Не знаю с чего начать. Пробую так,но тогда пользователь указывает именно номер строки которая покраситься

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim a As String 
    a=InputBox("Напишите кол-во строк")
    Rows(a).Interior.Color = vbBlue
End Sub
```

Comment: В заголовке - красить ячейку, в тексте - какую-то линию (строку?). Задал пользователь количество - 6... Дальше что? Красить через каждые 6 строк? Одну строку через 6 строк после активной ячейки? Строки через каждые 6 строк?

Comment: У оператора задача такая, что каждый она записывает n-строк(Число n она вводит при открытии книги). И чтобы разграничить день, необходимо покрасить всю линию. Получается у нее сегодня задача вбить данные на n строк, она указывает при открытии количество строк которые будет заполнять. Допустим 6 после этого нужно покрасить линию через 6 строк.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Находим последнюю строку, отсчитываем вниз указанное количество строк и красим найденную:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim lCnt As Long, lRw As Long

    lCnt = Int(Val(InputBox("Впишите необходимое кол-во строк", "ПРИВЕТ! НАЧИНАЕМ РАБОТАТЬ")))
    If lCnt <= 0 Then Exit Sub

    With Worksheets("kkk") ' указать имя нужного листа'
        lRw = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row + lCnt
        .Rows(lRw).Interior.Color = vbBlue
'        .Cells(lRw, 1).Resize(1, 5).Interior.Color = vbBlue ' заливаем только 5 ячеек строки ''
        .Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

Немного пояснений.

Если закрыть `InputBox` без ввода количества или вписать некорректное значение (например, букву или отрицательное число), получим ошибку. `Int(Val...))` помогает корректно ее обработать.

`With / End With` позволяет вычислять объект один раз, не  указывать родителя каждому подчиненному объекту, делает код читабельнее.

В этом примере последняя строка определяется для используемого диапазона (`.UsedRange.Rows.Count`). Если на листе используется фильтр, так надежнее, нежели `End(xlUp).Row`, т.к. последний не видит скрытых строк и если значения в конце таблицы будут отфильтрованы, последняя строка будет определена неправильно.

Но и применение `.UsedRange.Rows.Count` имеет недостаток. Таким методом находится последняя строка, но не с данными, а последняя строка ранее используемого диапазона (например, пользователь удалит значения последних строк, но сами строки с форматированием останутся).

Универсального метода нет, применять нужно по ситуации.

О диапазоне заливки. Зачем красить всю строку? Можно только ячейки таблицы (см. закомментированную строку)

О цвете. Если не нравится режущий глаза `vbBlue`, можно подобрать нужный цвет самостоятельно:

```
.Interior.Color = RGB(120, 180, 105)
```

Значения в скобках (от 0 до 255) - насыщенность красного, зеленого, синего цветов.

Answer (score 0):

Конструкция `Rows(a)` возвращает элемент с номером `a` из коллекции `Rows`. То есть вы получаете 6 или 7 строчку на листе. Вам же (судя по всему) нужно покрасить строчку на 6 или 7 строк ниже последней на листе.

Если задачу я понял верно, то необходимо следующее:

1. Определить последнюю строку на листе
2. Запросить точное количество строк, которое нужно отступить
3. закрасить нужную строку

***Первое*** решается путем получения номера строки последней заполненной ячейки в столбце, который заполняется на каждой строке. В большинстве таблиц бывают такие столбцы, которые должны быть заполнены в каждой строке. Это может быть номер по порядку, текущая дата / время или что-то еще. Вот по этому столбцу нужно найти нижнюю заполненную ячейку. Допустим, у нас есть лист `sh` с названием `"Рабочий лист"`, в котором столбец `A` заполняется всегда. Тогда нужный код будет выглядеть так:

```
Dim lastRow as Long
lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, sh.Range("A1").Column).End(xlUp).Row
```

Здесь:

- `sh.Rows.Count` - возвращает количество строк на листе, таким образом мы получим номер самой последней строки на листе.
- `sh.Range("A1").Column` - возвращает номер столбца указанной ячейки
- `sh.Cells(Row, Column)` - возвращает ячейку, которая расположена в указанной строке и указанном столбце. Таким образом, `sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, sh.Range("A1").Column)` возвратит самую нижнюю ячейку в столбце `A`.
- `Range.End(xlUp)` - возвращает объект `Range`, который соответствует крайней заполненной ячейки в этом столбце, при этом заполнение проверяется в направлении от ячейки, к которой применяется данный метод, в указанном направлении (здесь `xlUp` - вверх от последней ячейки на листе)
- `Range.Row` - возвращает номер нужной строки

***Второе*** вы уже описали сами. Однако, для номера строк лучше использовать тип `Long`, так как над этим значением придется проводить арифметические операции.

```
Dim a as Long
a = CLng(InputBox("Напишите кол-во строк"))
```

***Третье*** тоже никаких проблем вызвать не должно.

```
sh.Rows(lasRow + a).Interior.Color = vbBlue
```

Собственно возможный пример полностью:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim a As Long, lastRow as Long, sh as Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Рабочий лист")
    a = CLng(InputBox("Напишите кол-во строк"))
    lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, sh.Range("A1").Column).End(xlUp).Row
    sh.Rows(lasRow + a).Interior.Color = vbBlue
End Sub
```

Comment: Зачем `sh.Range("A1").Colum`? Можно явно указать номер столбца ("A" или 1). При открытии книги нет еще понятия активного листа и залита будет строка на листе с индексом 1 (первый лист слева)

Comment: Затем, чтоб избежать магических констант и показать опу, что именно здесь подразумевалось и что в этом месте можно использовать переменное значение, получаемое от объекта диапазона.

Comment: По поводу листа - переделал на вызов по имени. Так опу будет понятнее.

Comment: *чтоб избежать магических констант* - так Вы же сами применяете еще более магические константы - `xlUp`, `vbBlue` :)

Comment: Данные константы документированы и составляют словарные перечисления. В то время как указание простого значения ничего не говорит о том, что оно может означать

Comment: В данном случае совершенно незачем добавлять вычисления и усложнять читаемость кода. Если нужно, показать в комментариях.